# Form can't be rendered correctly in Chrome and Safari on both MacBook and Ubuntu

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Following URL (no worries, it is Australia Road and Traffic service website, used to book a driver test) can't be rendered correctly in Chrome and Mac on both MacBook and Ubuntu but can display correctly in Chrome and IE on Windows. Can any expert tell why? I tried  Chrome "view source" and "Inspect Element" but have no clue due to my limited knowledge.

Below are image that is displayed incorrectly.Sorry I don't have a Windows machine at hand so can't post the correct image.

Appreciate if anyone can shed some lights on it...

[image: it displayed incorrectly]

https://www.myrta.com/wps/portal/extvp/myrta/licence/tbs/tbs-login/!ut/p/b1/04_SjzQ0MbE0NjYz1Y_Qj8pLLMtMTyzJzM9LzAHxo8ziDTxcA8JCjcwNLYxNXQw83ZzNnQz9AwwNnA2BCiJBCnAARwNC-r30o5Ly87MdQ1KLS3zy0zPz9MP1o_Bq8jZGV2AQ7Glm4OkUGuYf5mhsaBFCQIG7GVwBbmf7eeTnpurnRuVYZGd66gIA3kjoLQ!!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the answer - after setting the browser language to English, everything back to normal. But I don't why….

Anyone have a hint?